# Avg() function returns '0E-20' instead of '0' in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have used `avg()` function in a SQL query in PostgreSQL.

When I run the query, I get `0E-20` as the result instead of `0` (zero).

The query is as below.

```
SELECT AVG(salary) 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Note: I have only one employee record whose salary is zero.

How can I get `0` as result instead of the special response?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh column data type is 'BIGINT'

Comment: That result can't happen if the column really is `bigint`. Sounds more like it's defined as `real` or `double precision`. Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link) and add the `create table` statement and the `insert` statement you used for that one row. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `salary` column contains floating point data, the average you are seeing could just be due to rounding error, while logically it is actually zero.  Some options here would be to use `ROUND` or `FLOOR`:

```
SELECT FLOOR(AVG(salary)) AS avg_salary   -- or ROUND(AVG(salary))
FROM EMPLOYEE
```